# как создать массив и наполнить случайными числами? Циклы не использовать. php

Tags: php, массивы

Создать массив на N элементов и наполнить его случайными числами. Циклы  использовать нельзя... помогите плиз как это реализовать

Comment: почему нельзя использовать циклы? Это олимпиадная задача?

Comment: @Sergiks думаю, задача на знание функций php, хотя такое на собеседовании знакомый встретил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$e = range(0,100);shuffle($e);var_dump($e);
```

Вам надо было почитать больше про функции php. 
range возвращает массив упорядоченных чисел от 0 до 100 (N) в данном случае

shuffle его перемешивает.

получается массив случайных чисел.

циклы там, конечно же, используются, но в реализациях функций. вот если бы вас попросили реализовать перемешивание массива без shuffle, было бы гораздо полезней для вас.

если у вас это какое-то задание, вы можете - забавы ради - представить два варианта - выше и еще один, основанный на goto со счетчиком. goto не является циклом, поэтому вы можете создать пустой массив, сгенерировать случайное число в массив, увеличить счетчик, после того как счетчик достигнет N, прыгнуть дальше. Формальные требования выполнены, применено достаточно извращенное решение.

в дополнение к извращенным решениям ниже, наверняка кто-нибудь придумает вариант с `random_bytes` или вызовом `/dev/random`

Comment: imho недостаток этого решения в неслучайности набора чисел. Истинно случайные скорее всего включают повторы одних значений и «дырки» в других.

Comment: для  видов распределений случайных чисел существуют вполне нормальные названия - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657254/normally-distributed-random-numbers-vs-uniformly-distributed-random-number, а чувакам стоило конкретизировать задачу.

Answer (score 3):

Создать массив нужной длины с помощью [`array_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-pad.php). Функцией [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) заполнить случайным [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rand.php) значением каждый элемент:

```
function randarr( $N, $min = 0, $max = 100) {
    return array_map(
        function() use( $min, $max) {
            return rand( $min, $max);
        },
        array_pad( [], $N, 0)
    );
}

print_r( randarr(5));
print_r( randarr(5, 22, 24));
print_r( randarr(5, 0, 1E9));
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 93
    [1] => 83
    [2] => 76
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 88
)
Array
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 23
    [2] => 22
    [3] => 22
    [4] => 24
)
Array
(
    [0] => 289735940
    [1] => 435158592
    [2] => 650113843
    [3] => 744380869
    [4] => 830975526
)
*/
```

[Рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/nGpi53).

Answer (score 2):

Ну и я добавлю ещё один извращённый способ

```
$n = 3;
$l = 2;
$randNumber = rand((10**($l-1))**n,(10**($l-1))**n+1);
$resultArray = str_split($randNumber,$l);
```

немного разъясню
`rand` возвращает случайное число, мы строим простой диапозон от числа `A` до числа `B` где `(10**($l-1))**n` это `10 в степени длина минус 1 и в степени N` и `B` собственно `10 в степени длина минус 1 и в степени N плюс 1`, в результате получаем некое псевдо случайное число длинной `N*L` символов, после разбиваем строку в моссив по длине `L` и получаем искомое `массив случайныхх чисел N длинны`...

p.s. Работать будет только на php ^ 5.6 (для версий ниже есть функция `pow`) ну и `n*l` ограничено длиной максимальной длины числа `randmax`.

Comment: ...демонство ваще