# Cформиовать массив php

Tags: php, php7

сформировать массив случайных чисел от -50 до 50 из 10 элементов

- вывести массив
- перемешать массив (вывести массив)
- отсортировать массив по убыванию (вывести массив)

Вот часть кода, но как перемешать и по убыванию сделать и при этом каждый раз выводить?

```
 function rand_arr( $N, $min = -50, $max = 50) 
            {
                return array_map(
                    function() use( $min, $max) 
                    {
                        return rand( $min, $max);
                    },
                    array_pad( [], $N, 0)
                );
            }
            
            foreach(rand_arr(10) as $arr)
            {
               echo $arr." ";
            }
```

Comment: перемешать и отсортировать в РНР есть встроенные функции. выводить точно так же. только чтобы "каждый раз выводить" массив надо сначала сохранить в переменную

Comment: @Ипатьев понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы плохо читали ответ

[как создать массив и наполнить случайными числами? Циклы не использовать. php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544574/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-php)

из которого Вы и взяли часть кода.

```php
<?php
$arr = array_map(function() {
            return rand( -50, 50);
        },
        array_pad( [], 10, 0)
    );

var_dump( $arr );

shuffle( $arr );

var_dump( $arr );

rsort( $arr );

var_dump( $arr );
```